# How to map java.lang.Object in .proto file [Protobuf]

Tags: protocol-buffers

How can I map `java.lang.Object` in `.proto` file. I'd like to have smth like:

```
message User {
 string name = 1;
 Object field = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the strangeness of your requirement for a moment: serialize your Java object to `byte[]` (formally implementing [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), or any way you want) and use protobuf value type [`bytes`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto?csw=1#scalar).

But this is really not the way to use protobuf. It's meant to transfer **data**, not **objects**. What of your object you would like to transfer over the wire? You cannot serialize methods and nontrivial object dependencies anyway. Only value types and simple structures (arrays, maps). So declare a proto message which reflects the data structure of your object, and serialize to that instead of `byte[]`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea cause I wanna send Object type, it means that it can be String, Long, Double, Client, whatever and I wanna handle it properly on client side. Now I am looking at google.protobuf.Any type.

Comment: [Proto3 doc website](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any): "_An `Any` contains an arbitrary serialized message as `bytes`_". So instead of implementing `Serializable`, you will have to implement `pack()` and `unpack()`. No difference. There is no magic in protobuf which would send an arbitrary object for you.

Comment: ok, but it makes me to handle a message, for instance if I have a map<string, Any> and any can be String and custom Object I should create at least two handlers for it.