# protobuf3 JsonFormat InvalidProtocolBufferException Unrecognized character

Tags: java, gson, protocol-buffers, guava, proto3

I am trying to convert json to proto message object, but if there are some 
characters in json like $ or . or _ I get an InvalidProtocolBufferException.
My proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package messages;
option java_multiple_files = true;

message Main {
    A a = 1;
}

message A {
    repeated B b = 1;
}

message B {
    repeated C c = 1;
}

message C {
    map<string, bytes> d = 1;
}
```

Java code:

```
 String json = "{\n" +
        "  \"a\" : {\n" +
        "    \"b\" : [ {\n" +
        "      \"c\" : [ {\n" +
        "        \"d\" : {\n" +
        "          \"money\" : [ \"100$\" ]\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      } ]\n" +
        "    } ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}";
    Main.Builder builder = Main.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, builder);
    System.out.println(builder.build());
```

output:

```
  com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: $

        at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1065)
        at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:273)
```

Comment: Could you please add problematic json and protobuf definition of type User ?

Comment: I've done it, please check

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your problem is connected with declaration of type C, inside of it in proto definiton you have `map<string,bytes> d = 1;` Which on Java side will be: `Map<String, ByteString>` And In your Json you have something that "looks like" String-String map.

Let's do quick experiment and try to convert your Main type into json:

```
Main main = Main.newBuilder().setA(
        A.newBuilder().addB(
                B.newBuilder().addC(
                        C.newBuilder().putD("money", 
                                ByteString.copyFrom("100$".getBytes()))
                )
        )
).build();

System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().print(main));
```

The output will be

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": [{
      "c": [{
        "d": {
          "money": "MTAwJA=="
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see we don't have `100$` but encoded version `MTAwJA==` and if you will try to convert this json to object using protobuf you will not have an error.

So in my opinion - either encode values in your d map during conversion to json (or convert to json using protobuf), or change protobuf declaration

Comment: Thank you Michal, I got it as you, I think it's impossible to convert from json to proto using JsonFormat in this case. I just wanna map java.lang.Object to proto message. I have a data object with Map<String, Object> data and I need to send it using protobuf.

Comment: In my opinion it wll not be possible without additional processing of json (on sender side), or without change in proto definition. It is possible that in your case, on sender side you can also use protobuf to serialize to json?

Comment: yeah, on both sides I use protobuf. I can do it anyway, but I have not known the right way yet. Now I decided to map it as map<string, bytes> as I got an answer from there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878400/how-to-map-java-lang-object-in-proto-file-protobuf

Comment: Ok, sorry - I did not understand you in the first place. I assume that it is not possible for your "object" to become protobuf object? If not so probably (as it was mentioned in link you've gave) you will need to serialize your object into byte array

Comment: Yeah, that's how I did - map<string,bytes>

Comment: The bottom line is I can't use this json transformation with string type (100$) to Message type byte<string, bytes>. I should use create message manually - ByteStream.copyFrom("100$".getBytes())